# How to differentiate the parent path and their children paths?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code, I am trying to monitor the creation of files. I gave the if-statement in the `on_created` function to differentiate the `folder1` and their subpaths.

When I create a file in `folder1`, it prints the `Parent path` message but when I create a file in other paths, it still prints the `Parent path` message. Although this time it should print the `Child path` message

```
import os
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import multiprocessing


class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        print(f'event type: {event.event_type} path : {event.src_path}')
        if folder1:
            print("Parent path")
        else:
            print("Child path")

def monitor_folders(path):
    event_handler = MyHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()

folder1 = "/home/bilal/Videos/folder1/"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    m1 = monitor_folders(folder1)
    m1.start()
    m1.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You took the meaning of `if folder1:` wrong. This expression evaluates the boolean value of `folder1` string, which will always be `True` unless it is an empty string.

## Solution

Add this import

```
from pathlib import Path
```

and change `if folder1:` to

```
if Path(event.src_path).parent.samefile(folder1):
```

This is the correct cross-platform compatible expression to evaluate whether the containing folder of the created file is the same as `folder1`.

## Result

Tested with debian 10 PC and python 3.8, `folder1 = "/mnt/ramdisk/"`.

```
event type: created path : /mnt/ramdisk/out3.xlsx
Parent path
event type: created path : /mnt/ramdisk/notebooks/out3.xlsx
Child path
```

Comment: `Pathlib` didn't work but `pathlib` worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's because in your if statement, you check the following condition: `folder1`.
This is the same as asking `bool(folder1) == True`. However, `folder1` is a variable that contains the string `"/home/bilal/Videos/folder1/"`. As string will always be `True` when it contains any characters and `False` when it's an empty string.

So your condition will always be `True` because `folder1` is always the same string and never changes.